# Using trigger in SQL Server to update version

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table with a few columns of data, plus two columns `rowId` and `rowVersion`, both of type `int`.

I want to increment the value of `rowVersion` each time the row is updated, so for example if the current value for `rowVersion` is 2, I want to be able to execute:

```
UPDATE table1
SET    name = 'John Smith'
WHERE  rowId = 1
  AND  rowVersion = 2;
```

and that the trigger will then increment `rowVersion` to 3

How can I do that?  TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER VersionTrigger 
        ON table1 
        after UPDATE
    AS 
       UPDATE table1 
       SET rowVersion = rowVersion +1 
       WHERE rowId IN (SELECT rowId FROM inserted)
    GO
```

Comment: I tried something like that before I posted the question but I tried `WHERE rowId = inserted.rowId` and that didn't work.  thx.

Comment: If more than row is updated then won't they all be given the same rowVersion value?

Comment: Every update in a row is treated as one,not mater how you write the update query